# How to set up a DataSource for TomEE+

Tags: java, netbeans, ejb, mariadb, apache-tomee

I have been trying to figure out how to set up NetBeans (v8.1) and TomEE+ (v1.7.4) to Accessing Data with EJBs.

I have been following along [The NetBeans E-commerce Tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html) (Affable Bean app) and I am stuck on [Accessing Data with EJBs](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html#access). Did all the edits as the tutorial states and get an error on run.

AffableBean log:

```
build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

Apache TomEE+ 1.7.4 Log:

```
Jun 15, 2016 8:26:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet ControllerServlet as unavailable
Jun 15, 2016 8:26:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [ControllerServlet] in web application [/AffableBean] threw load() exception
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [controller.ControllerServlet/categoryFacade] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [controller.ControllerServlet].
```

Apache TomEE+ 1.7.4:

```
INFO: Configuring PersistenceUnit(name=AffableBeanPU)
Jun 15, 2016 8:26:11 AM org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig deploy
WARNING: Found matching datasource: web/connpool but this one is not a JTA datasource
Jun 15, 2016 8:26:11 AM org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig deploy
WARNING: Found matching datasource: web/connpool but this one is not a JTA datasource
Jun 15, 2016 8:26:11 AM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AffableBean]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: PeristenceUnit AffableBeanPU <jta-data-source> points to a non jta managed Resource.  Update Resource "connpool" to "JtaManaged=true", use a different Resource, or delete the <jta-data-source> element and a default will be supplied if possible.
```

My codes for the persistence.xml is as per tutorial, which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AffableBeanPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>connpool</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

So my question is, how can I set up DataSource/EJB in my IDE so it can be run on my server? Irregardless of the Netbeans E-Commerce Tutorial.

EDITed: stuck on [Accessing Data with EJBs](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html#access).

Answer (score 1):

You can define your datasource as a global datasource (for all webapps) defining in the $TOMEE/conf/tomee.xml file or specific to your webapp in the $WEBAPP/WEB-INF/resources.xml file just like this

persistence.xml at webapp's src/META-INF dir

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
    version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="xyz">
        <jta-data-source>xyz</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property
                name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary"
                value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary" />
            <property
                name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary"
                value="oracle(maxEmbeddedBlobSize=-1,maxEmbeddedClobSize=-1)" />
            <property
                name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings"
                value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and data source defined at $WEBAPP/WEB-INF/resource.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
    <Resource
        id="xyz"
        type="DataSource">
        JdbcDriver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        JdbcUrl jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
        UserName myuser
        Password mypass
        JtaManaged true
        TestOnBorrow false
        MaxActive 20        
    </Resource>    
</tomee>
```

see http://tomee.apache.org/datasource-config.html and http://tomee.apache.org/common-datasource-configurations.html

Comment: thanks for the code and links. I will be testing later. The tutorial uses the data sources defined in $WEBAPP/src/conf/persistence.xml. Do you know if TomEE requires it to be in $WEBAPP/WEB-INF/resource.xml?

Comment: No, TomEE does not require a `$WEBAPP/src/conf/persistence.xml` nor a `$WEBAPP/WEB-INF/resource.xml`. Those certainly work, but create non-portable WAR files. Put the same lines in your `$TOMEE/tomee.xml` file and the configuration will live in the container instead.

Comment: Hello @Leo. Did some playing around with your suggestion in a resource.xml file. Build failed. From the server log: `SEVERE: FAIL ... ProductFacade: Missing required persistence.xml for PersistenceContext ref "em" to unit "AffableBeanPU"`. Guess it is needed in the persistence.xml file., at least for this tutorial. Will investigate further and report back, if I figure it out. I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction though, so thanks!

Comment: Hi @JonathanS.Fisher. Thank you for your response. What would be the benefit as to have it in the container as you suggested, as apposed to the way the tutorial is set up? One more thing for me to research I guess.

Comment: As you move the application between environments (desktop, dev, qc, test, prod) your hostname of the database might change. Having it in the environment instead of the application makes deployments much easier